# Columns won't horizontally align with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm unable to horizontally align my columns in bootstrap. What I'm wanting is the image to be on the left, and the text to be on the right, but it keep stacking vertically. Can I get some help with this?

From my understanding, `col-md-6` will split the page into 2 columns, and `col-xs-12` will stack them vertically on mobile, but it doesn't seem to be doing that for me. Is something I'm doing that's overriding the default bootstrap css?

[image: what it currently looks like]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
      img {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .btn {
        margin: auto;
      }
      .vertical-center {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
      }
      .left-text {
        text-align: left;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="verticalcenter">
    <div class="container vertical-center">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
        <img src="./profile.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-5">
        <div class="row left-text">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
            <h2>MyStackFlowethOver</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
            <h4>web developer</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
            <a href="#" class="" role="button" target="_blank">github</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
            <a href="#" class="" role="button" target="_blank">linkedin</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
            <a href="3" class="" role="button" target="_blank">twitter</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
            <a href="/blog" class="" role="button" target="_blank">blog</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
            <a href="./resume.pdf" class="" role="button" target="_blank">resume</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you need `<div class = "row">` for every row of content you want to insert. That could be messing up your layout.

Example from your code:

```
<div class = "row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
     <img src="./profile.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
```

and so on.

Comment: Bingo! For the record, this is the explanation for what @Anshul Bansal did in his answer

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your issue.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">
          img {
            width: 100%;
          }
          .btn {
            margin: auto;
          }
          .vertical-center {
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
          }
          .left-text {
            text-align: left;
          }

        </style>
      </head>
      <body class="verticalcenter">
        <div class="container vertical-center">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                <img src="./profile.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-5">
                <div class="row left-text">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                    <h2>MyStackFlowethOver</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                    <h4>web developer</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                    <a href="#" class="" role="button" target="_blank">github</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                    <a href="#" class="" role="button" target="_blank">linkedin</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                    <a href="3" class="" role="button" target="_blank">twitter</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                    <a href="/blog" class="" role="button" target="_blank">blog</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                    <a href="./resume.pdf" class="" role="button" target="_blank">resume</a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks! To clarify, your change was explained by the @trimkas, and resolved the issue I was having. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FYI In Bootstrap-4 there is no class like col-xs-* so you need to replace col-xs-12 with col-12 and you also forget you two columns to wrap with row class I have also checked in your code you need also put one meta tag in your head for require responsive site like

And the updated code is as Follow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
        img {
            width: 100%;
          }
          .btn {
            margin: auto;
          }
          .vertical-center {
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
          }
          .left-text {
            text-align: left;
          }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="verticalcenter">
    <div class="container vertical-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                <img src="./profile.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-5">
                <div class="row left-text">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                        <h2>MyStackFlowethOver</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                        <h4>web developer</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                        <a href="#" class="" role="button" target="_blank">github</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                        <a href="#" class="" role="button" target="_blank">linkedin</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                        <a href="3" class="" role="button" target="_blank">twitter</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                        <a href="/blog" class="" role="button" target="_blank">blog</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                        <a href="./resume.pdf" class="" role="button" target="_blank">resume</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I Think this will help you. Happy code :)